# Drupal menu item setting as active

Tags: drupal, menu, highlight

Here is my problem. I have a site in drupal and some menu structure. When the URL address is application/android/all android menu item is highlighted. However, when the URL address is application/android/16 android menu item is not highlighted.

My question is how to make everything that starts with /application/android/ to have highlighted android menu item?

Cheers,
Mladjo

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [Menu Trails](http://drupal.org/project/menutrails) module that provides this functionality.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

The Context module (http://drupal.org/project/context) can also set it, and it is useful for loads of other things. give it a try.